# map-only job - order

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a `csv` file. Say it has 2 splits, i.e., one block will be handled by the 1st `map()` task and the other by the 2nd `map()` task.

In the given csv I am replacing "0" with `false` and "1" with `true`. So I will be writing a map-only job for that. After the job completion, will I get the same order of the input file as result? As `shuffle` and `sort` are done after Map job.

Is there any way to get the same order of the input file as result?

Answer (score 3):

You can do `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`. This way, `shuffle` and `sort` won't happen.

However, there will be as many output files as there are map tasks (2 in this case). If you concatenate them, you'll get what you want. This probably doesn't matter since in most cases, Hadoop let you supply a folder wherever file is expected.

Comment: So we neeed to concatenate the file?we will not get every one into same part file?

Comment: You won't get every one into same part file. Each map task will produce a part file.

Comment: So am I able to concatenate the resultant in map() function it self?

Comment: You can't do that in a map function. Each split will go to a different map task and you can't communicate in the map phase. Why do you care? If the output is going to some other map reduce job, you can supply the output folder as its input. If not, you can use `cat` to concatenate them. In this case, Hadoop won't help you in terms of performance.

Comment: If you really want to. You can set `key` as the byte offset and `value` as a tuple combining you original key and value. And then, you can set the number of reduce tasks to 1. This way, you can get what you want by emitting everything you receive in the reducer.

Comment: I thought it can be a map-only job.But it should also include reduce() too .am I right?So in reducer I want to jst emit the incoming values right? so all the map resultant will get concatenated.If it is a very huge file, am i able to set reducer to 1.

Comment: You can set reducer to 1. And on most environment, that's the default if you don't explicitly set the number of reducers. The performance won't be good. But you probably can't get better.

Comment: Besides, if you want to get everything in the same part file, you can't have more than 1 reducer. Otherwise, you will get many output files as there are reducer tasks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49298/discussion-between-unmesha-sreeveni-and-haozhun)

Comment: Please see my discussion

Comment: Easiest way to process your whole csv file by single mapper is to override isSplitable method of FileInputFormat and set it to return false, when you do that whole file is procssed by instance of mapper and if you set reducers to 0 too then output order of lines will be exactly same as input.

Comment: @rVr I understand that you comment answers OP's question. But what  is the point of using map reduce if you set map to 1 and reduce to 0?

Comment: @Haozhun:if we are having map and reducer, again the output data will be in sorted order.right?again the order changes.